# transparent view or button over a uitextview with touches passed to it

Tags: iphone, ios, button, uitextview, transparent

I have a uitextview and for some reasons I would it was not editable but that it became editable when the user touches it. I thought to put on it another view or a button in a such way that this view or button intercepts the user touch and passes it to the `uitextview`.

Is it possible? How could I make a such transparent view or button?

Thanks,

Fran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ummm, did you mean, you want the UITextView to be not editable, but the view or button should catch the tap? why??

but yep you can,

just create a UIButton with `[button backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` then catch the button tap and in that method call `[textview becomeFirstResponder];`

but if you are doing this roundabout thing just because for unknown reason, the UITextView is uneditable by tapping, try setting `[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

or maybe some other views frame is covering the textview and is not letting the  tap event through to the uitextview. try putting it on top of everything not below.

Comment: I'm trying to bypass the impossibility to detect the links in an editable textview.

Comment: Oh, what you should instead do is... in -(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)sender { method, turn on dataDetectors: [textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeAll]; You can change teh dataDetector to detect only phone numbers, links, email etc